# Fastest way to match two tables by count of matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I want to match two tables to determine a campaign code when it is unknown. In order to match these tables there is a formula that states how many "service codes" match and how many "discount codes" match.

I have this running in 1 minute for 100 records - I need it to run in seconds as I have millions of orders to process. Can anyone help?

The campaign table is structured like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[all_campaigns_t_unpacked](
    Offername_Full [varchar](255) NULL,
    Campaign_Code [varchar](3) NULL,
    Service_Code [varchar](5) NULL,
    Discount_Code [varchar](5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The orders table is structured like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED](
    Service_Order_ID [bigint] NOT NULL,
    Service_Code [varchar](5) NULL,
    Discount_Code [varchar](5) NULL,
    Campaign_Code [varchar](5) NULL,
    Campaign_Code_Name [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I tried two methods (one with top 1 with ties/row_number and the other using cross apply). I also used a CTE instead of the first temp table but with this small test the temp table was faster.

Method 1 - window function - 91 rows in 1min 25sec

```
drop table if exists #cte
SELECT          A.Service_Order_ID
            ,   Service_Code
            ,   COALESCE(Discount_Code,'BLANK') Discount_Code
            ,   Campaign_Code
            ,   COALESCE(Campaign_Code_Name,'UNKNOWN') Campaign_Code_Name
into #CTE
FROM [dbo].[CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED] A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 
        Service_Order_ID 
    FROM
        [CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED]) B
    ON 
        A.Service_Order_ID = B.Service_Order_ID


;with CTE2 AS (
SELECT 
TOP 1 WITH TIES
        UP.Service_Order_ID
    ,   UP.Campaign_Code_Name
    ,   UP.Campaign_Code CAMPAIGN_CODE  
    ,   CC.CAMPAIGN_CODE CAMPAIGN_CODE_CHECKED
FROM 
    #CTE UP
INNER JOIN
    all_campaigns_t_unpacked CC
    ON  
        UP.BILLING_CD = CC.Service_Code
    AND UP.ITEM_DISCOUNT_CD = CC.DISCOUNT_CODE
GROUP BY    
        UP.Service_Order_ID
    ,   UP.Campaign_Code_Name
    ,   UP.Campaign_Code
    ,   CC.CAMPAIGN_CODE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UP.Service_Order_ID ORDER BY 10 * sum(case when UP.ITEM_DISCOUNT_CD = 'BLANK' then 0 else 1 end) + count(*) desc)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2 ORDER BY Service_Order_ID
```

Method 2 - cross apply - 91 rows in 1 min 1 second

```
drop table if exists #cte

SELECT          A.Service_Order_ID
            ,   Service_Code
            ,   COALESCE(Discount_Code,'BLANK') Discount_Code
            ,   Campaign_Code
            ,   COALESCE(Campaign_Code_Name,'UNKNOWN') Campaign_Code_Name
into #CTE
FROM [dbo].[CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED] A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 
        Service_Order_ID 
    FROM
        [CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED]) B
    ON 
        A.Service_Order_ID = B.Service_Order_ID

SELECT C.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Service_Order_ID FROM #CTE) A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
            Service_Order_ID
        ,   Campaign_Code_Name
        ,   CAMPAIGN_CODE
        ,   CAMPAIGN_CODE_CHECKED   
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                UP.Service_Order_ID
            ,   UP.Campaign_Code_Name
            ,   UP.Campaign_Code CAMPAIGN_CODE
            ,   CC.CAMPAIGN_CODE CAMPAIGN_CODE_CHECKED  
            ,   UP.ITEM_DISCOUNT_CD
            FROM #CTE UP
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT * 
                FROM all_campaigns_t_unpacked C
                WHERE 
                    UP.BILLING_CD = C.Service_Code
                AND UP.ITEM_DISCOUNT_CD = C.DISCOUNT_CODE
            ) CC
        ) B
    WHERE 
            A.Service_Order_ID = B.Service_Order_ID
    GROUP BY 
            Service_Order_ID
        ,   Campaign_Code_Name
        ,   CAMPAIGN_CODE
        ,   CAMPAIGN_CODE_CHECKED   
    ORDER BY 10 * sum(case when ITEM_DISCOUNT_CD ='BLANK' then 0 else 1 end) + count(*) desc
        ) C
ORDER BY C.Service_Order_ID
```

I am fully aware that the expression in the order by statement is likely causing issues, but to give some insight there is reason for this calculation.

If the Campaign Table looks like this

| Offername_Full | Campaign_Code | Service_Code | Discount_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Offer 1 | 001 | AB001 | 10001 |
| Offer 1 | 001 | AB002 | 10002 |
| Offer 1 | 001 | AB003 | 10003 |
| Offer 2 | 001 | AB001 | BLANK |
| Offer 2 | 001 | AB004 | BLANK |
| Offer 2 | 001 | AB005 | BLANK |

and the Order looks like this

| Service_Order_ID | Service_Code | Discount_Code | Campaign_Code | Campaign_Code_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | AB001 | 10001 | NULL | NULL |
| 100001 | AB002 | 10002 | NULL | NULL |
| 100001 | AB004 | BLANK | NULL | NULL |
| 100001 | AB005 | BLANK | NULL | NULL |

If we did not calculate the match on Service_Code only would be 2 for offer 1 and 3 for offer 2, by weighting matches for discount_code 2 we get a "score of 12 for offer 1 and 3 for offer 2 -> offer 1 is the most likely

To give orders of magnitude

The campaign table (all_campaigns_t_unpacked) has 10,000+ campaign codes and some 300k+ rows total
The order table (CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED) has 172 million rows and 27 million unique service_order_IDs

Indexes

- CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED
  IX_SERVICE_ORDER_ID_CAMPAIGN - non clustered([SERVICE_ORDER_ID] ASC, [CAMPAIGN_CODE] ASC)INCLUDE([SERVICE_CODE],[DISCOUNT_CODE],[CAMPAIGN_CODE_NAME])
- all_campaigns_t_unpacked
  IX_SERVICE_CODE_DISCOUNT_CODE([SERVICE_CODE] ASC, [DISCOUNT_CODE] ASC)INCLUDE([OFFERNAME_FULL],[CAMPAIGN_CODE])

Statistics

- CODES_ADDED_STATS ON [CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED] 
      (SERVICE_ORDER_ID, CAMPAIGN_CD_NM, CAMPAIGN_CD)
- all_campaigns_t_unpacked_STATS ON [all_campaigns_t_unpacked]  
      (CAMPAIGN_CODE)

Comment: Why do you need this to run in one second, it sounds like a one-time job? also, it's better if you add the indexes to the table definitions so one can see the uniquity etc

Comment: In both of your attempts you have TOP with no ORDER BY. This means that you have no way of knowing which row(s) you are going to get .

Comment: (1) What indexes do you have on your tables? If none, adding indexes on `CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED(Service_Order_ID)` and `all_campaigns_t_unpacked(Service_Code, Discount_Code)` would be a good place to start. (2) What is your intent of the self join for `CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED` in your `#CTE` query? You have a `TOP` constraint but no `ORDER BY` clause. That can be a red frag from a consistency aspect (but not necessarily a performance issue).

Comment: The TOP 100 is just to restrict the pull to 100 orders only - this could be in another table, but this does not seem to be where the problem is. If I ran this on the whole table it would run for days

This job will be done nightly with about 100k records so it needs to run fast that 1 records per second

Indexes are shown above

Comment: Why no clustered index?

Comment: On second look, it appears that your data is severely denormalized. I think the first step would be to map the data to a set of normalized tables: (1) Map distinct Service_Code, Discount_Code, and Campaign_Code values to three lookup tables having an id and a name. (2) Map distinct offers and service orders to their own tables. (3) Define junction tables to represent the many-to-many relationships between offers and service order and the service, discount, and campaign tables. (Example: OfferDiscount would have OfferId and DiscountId columns). Define PKs, FKs, and lots of indexes. ...

Comment: ... From there you may start working on a query to (1) examine each combination of offer and service order, (2) calculate the number of Service, Discount, and Campaign codes in common, (3) apply your custom criteria calculation, and (4) select the best matches. This will still be an expensive comparison O(N x M), but with normalized data the magnitude of both M and N should be reduced, and by matching ID values instead of text, teh comparisons will also be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i'd do something like this:

1. Batch up 1M or whatever rows of CODES_ADDED_UNPACKED into a temptable with clustered index like: ServiceCode, DiscountCode (you name your fields different in different places which is confusing but whatever).
2. Create clustered index on ServiceCode, DiscountCode on all_campaigns_t_unpacked if you can.
3. This will hopefully allow doing a merge join between the temp table and all_campaigns_t_unpacked which should be pretty fast.
4. Do the normal join where you group by your formula and insert to another temp table which is indexed by OrderId. You can probably do a row_number grouping and remove all but first row and it should be fast enough.
5. Now you should be able to quickly join back and update your Order table. I'm not sure if the logic is that whole order gets same campaign code but since you don't mention anything i'm gonna assume it so
6. Change your system so you assign campaign code when you create order
7. ...
8. Profit

I don't think it should take more than a few days/weeks, plus, you should be able to run this during the day, since you do very little "on the fly" updating and all updates should be by indexes so the locking window shouldn't be too big

In case of misjoins i'd play around with indexes / try forcing merge join to see if it works

Comment: I'll take a look at this and see if it works any better